# Youtube - Content ID

Tags: youtube-api

I've been reading a lot recently about the Content ID that youtube provides. As how it works and how to use it from the Youtube provided interface is clear, I did not find any API reference for this.

Could some one point me to the portion of the Youtube api that deals with this ?

I have to mention that I'm intending to be a copyright owner and I would like to use the youtube api, if possible, to manage rights and find the content which other people have uploaded. Content which by copyright is owned by me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your channel must be a partner channel, then you must enable the ContentID API from the console\services:
[Google Developer Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)

After that you can refer to the online documentation at:
[YouTube Content ID API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/)

But please be noted that you cannot see the "ContentID API" directly on the console, you must contact the Youtube for it, and this what happened with us.
We were developing an automated tool that uses Youtube Data API & Youtube ContentID API.

Comment: After verified my google developer account in youtube, the youtube Content ID api still does not show up on the Google Console. Do I have to contact YouTube Office directly?