# How can a YouTube management webservice apply for a CMS account to use the Content ID API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

For a webservice to be able to manage the channels controlled by a YouTube partner, not only does the service have to oauth as the partner using the *youtubepartner* scope, it has to get permission to use the YouTube Content ID API.

The [form](https://www.youtube.com/content_id_signup) for signing up to use Content ID assumes that the applicant is managing their own content, not that of others. When I applied using this form I got a fast rejection because "your channel's current level of viewership suggests that other rights management tools may be better suited to your needs". But YouTube channel popularity has no relevance to a business that wants to manage the content of others.

"Your channel is not popular enough" is the only reply you get, no matter what explanations of your needs you put on the form, even if you say you manage a large number of copyrights to try to avoid an immediate automated rejection.

Therefore, how should one bypass this brick wall and apply for Content ID API access as a service? There are many service providers in [YouTube's Creator Services Directory](https://servicesdirectory.withyoutube.com/) that are labelled as certified for the Content ID API. How did they obtain API access as a service provider?

Comment: well, I suggest you to check the [YouTube Content ID API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/) to know more about it. It explain here all the guides that you can do with it. I also found out in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964905) that to get access to YouTube Content ID API you first need to apply here. https://www.youtube.com/content_id_signup?internalcountrycode=GB. And you must be a partner to do it. For more information, check also this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849114).

Comment: KENdi, the link you've provided to apply to use the Content ID API is the same one that I quoted and have been using. The API documentation says to go to www.youtube.com/partner to learn about becoming a partner, which now redirects to the [YouTube Creator Hub](https://www.youtube.com/yt/creators/benefit-levels.html?noapp=1), which says nothing about how a service provider can become a partner.

Comment: The final Q&A to which you linked says "you must contact the Youtube for [API access]". However to contact YouTube directly you must already be a partner. Catch-22. How do I contact YouTube outside filling in the Content ID form?